# LibreOffice Calc, how to count the number of columns in a table?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

My request is very simple.

I just opened a csv file with **LibreOffice Calc**, and I notice that the **columns** go from A to BL.
I need to know **how many columns** there are, in this A-BL range.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just execute the following three steps:

1. Navigate to Column `BL` (manually or using the navigator: Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to open the navigator, enter "BL" at the column text field and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>;
2. Select all the cells from `BL1` to `A1`: press and hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, hit <kbd>Pos1</kbd> (may be <kbd>Home</kbd> on your keyboard);
3. Check the status bar. It shows the selection's size - 64 columns:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @tohuwawohu. (1) and (2) do not work; but (3) works well.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it Those weren' meant as alternatives, but as three successive steps - step 1 and 2 create the selection, step 3 evaluates its size.

Comment: Oh thanks. Perhaps I just found an easier way: highlight a row from column A to column BL, and then read the status bar saying "Selected 1 row, 64 columns"

Comment: Yes, there's no difference in the result when you build the selection from left to right or otherwise. But you'll have to put the selection manually, exactly as needed. This is ensured by the steps i've described (should work with many more columns, too, where selecting them manually may be painstaiking. Juping to the last column as described and creating the selection by "jumping back" should work in any case, independent of the columns's count.